# Reseting a PHY from U-boot

Tags: linux-device-driver, u-boot

I am building a custom board that is based off of an existing evaluation module for a processor. On the evaluation module there is a MCU that handles most of the boot time configuration. Along with this, the MCU forces a reset on the PHY chips so that the PHY chips can begin communication. On my custom board there will **not** be an MCU to perform the reset and this the processor must perform the reset.

How would I go about performing the reset from u-boot?

My processor is connected to an SPI -> GPIO expander and this must reset the Phy through the use of SPI. I will not be performing an NFS boot so I do not need the Phys to be accessable from u-boot, but they do need to be reset before the Linux Kernel is booted in order for the kernel drivers to set it up correctly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

As per MII standards, your PHY chip will have basic mode control register at address 0x00. Look in PHY chip datasheet under 'PHY MDIO register Description'.
In U-Boot either phy-chip driver ( example marvell, vitesse etc.) if found, otherwise generic phy-driver will perform the phy reset.